# What is the exact time for start of the match in IPL 2018?

Tags: cricket, media, indian-premier-league

I have heard this time [IPL match starts at 7 pm instead of 8 pm](https://www.firstpost.com/firstcricket/sports-news/ipl-11-could-see-mid-season-transfers-7-pm-start-for-evening-matches-4236663.html). Also, day match starts at 3 pm instead of 4 pm.

Note: I am asking about an exact time when players come out on the ground, not considering pre-match program like [Extra Innings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraaa_Innings_T20) or [Kent Cricket Live](http://www.hotstar.com/tv/best-of-kent-cricket-live-2016/12298).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[IPLT20.com](https://www.iplt20.com/) clearly shows the match time as 4:00pm IST and 8:00pm IST, so this is the time the match will start.

[image: ipl]

[Source](https://www.iplt20.com/schedule)

And from [Star Sports TV guide](http://tvguide.starsports.com/) schedule for these matches are:

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

So, you should tune in at around 3:50pm IST and 7:50pm IST to skip the pre-match program.

Answer (score -1):

Evening match:-
Complementary time:
15:00 to 16:00,
Players playing time:
16:00 to 19:30,
Complementory:
19:30 to 19:45.

Night matche timing:-
Complementory:
19:45 to 20:00,
Players playing time:
20:00 to 23:30 & 
Complementory
23:30 to 23:59.